# File extention for xaml package

Tags: vb.net, file-extension, textrange

I tried saving data from my rich text box using the TextRange to save in xamlpackage format, however my question is basic, what extension should the file have, if I use Xaml, the normal wpf xaml files would not be capable of opening as they are not xamlpackages, could you please tell me the proper extension for xamlpackage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML files are extension independent.

Extension are used in VS to be associated with XAML designer, and XAML compiler (to compile it to BAML, and .cs files)

If you need to load/save XAML,  you should look at [XAMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx), [XAMLWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) class.

In XAMLReader, XAMLWriter you can specify file with any extension to load/save data in XAML format.

Comment: so, I can use any extention for my xamlpackage data type in textrange.save method?

Comment: yes, any extension is fine. textrange.Save/textrange.Load will work same way regardless of extension.